# Laravel print query error

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in routes:

```
Route::get('forum/{fname}/{fid}', 'viewForum@showForum');
```

in controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewForum extends Controller 
{
    public function showForum($fname, $fid)
    {
        return View::make('forum', [
            'forums'    => DB::table('forums')
                ->where('id', $fid)
                ->where('seo-name', $fname)
                ->select()
                ->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And in the layout:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@foreach($forums as $forum)
{{ $forum->name }}
@endforeach
@stop
```

It's ok, but when I write bad {fname} or {fid} then nothing prints, white page, but i wan't to show error, how can I do it? I've created same with viewProfile :

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewProfile extends Controller 
{
    public function showProfile($uname, $uid)
    {
        $u = DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', $uid)
            ->where('name', $uname)
            ->first();

        return View::make('users', [
            'username'  => $u->name,
            'userid'    => $u->id,
            'email'     => $u->email,
            'regdate'   => $u->created_at
        ]);
    }
}
```

In this code error prints, but in first nope, why? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance

I'm fixed, I just added this code:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
@forelse($forums as $forum)
{{ $forum->name }}
@empty
<div class="alert alert-danger">Forum not found</div>
@endforelse
@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to show all errors,
Set `APP_ENV=local` in you `.env` file.
Allow recursive 777 permission to `/vendor` and `/storage` folder.

It should work.. 
also make sure that in '/config/databse.php' file `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,` or `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,` is written.

You should also see that `DB::table('forums')
                ->where('id', $fid)
                ->where('seo-name', $fname)
                ->select()
                ->get();`
return a 2D array, and you are required a single dimension array.
Once you be able to show errors you will find all errors easily. :)